# Typescript: static method vs function defined outside class

Tags: typescript

What are the practical differences between a static class method, and a function defined outside a class (at the top of the file) in TypeScript?

I know that there are differences regarding visibilty from other classes and files. When visibility is not a concern though (the function/method is only used in one class), when should we use static methods rather than functions defined outside any classes.

Example:

```
export class Foo {
  
  constructor(bar: string) {
    Foo.shout(bar);
  }

  private static shout(content: string) {
    console.log(string.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

VS

```
export class Foo {
  
  constructor(bar: string) {
    shout(bar);
  }

}

function shout(content: string) {
  console.log(string.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Besides technical differences you should consider architectural ones: does the method actually have anything to do with the class? Does it belong there?

Comment: In many languages, a static method is just a global function with a funky name, usually with better access control.

Comment: @axiac - Yes, that's true for C++ and probably several others. It's not true for JavaScript or TypeScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What are the practical differences between a static class method, and a function defined outside a class (at the top of the file) in TypeScript?

Not all that many:

1. Code using the static method must have access to the class; code using a standalone function must have access to the standalone function instead.
2. Using the static method technically involves a property lookup on the class's constructor function; using a standalone function doesn't. In practice, this will be optimized such that it doesn't matter.
3. The code **in** the static method will have access to the constructor function's parent constructor function via `super` (something that's fairly unique to JavaScript); code in a standalone function does not (because there is no parent constructor).
4. Specifically in regard to your example: Your standalone `shout` function is private to the module in which it appears; the static method on `Foo` is accessible from other modules that import `Foo`.

Slightly closer to opinion-land:

5. A standalone function is *standalone*, it doesn't provide much context for what it is or where it's defined to someone reading the code. A static method provides more context, via the class name. **But**, if you're using modules (as you seem to be), the `import` provides some context for the standalone function.

> ...when should we use static methods rather than functions defined outside any classes.

That's largely a matter of opinion and style, so off-topic for Stack Overflow. If your team feels the need for consistency using some set of rules, agree a set and be consistent.